# La búsqueda no trabaja en vista de lista poblada de matriz JSON en Android

Tags: android, json

Siempre que intente hacer clic en el botón de búsqueda, la aplicación se detiene.

**APIConnector.java**

```
public class ApiConnector {

public JSONArray GetAllContacts()
{
    // URL for getting all customers
    String url = "http://192.168.100.2/android_connect/get_all.php";

    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Log Errors Here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
public JSONArray GetContactDetails(int ContactID)
{
    // URL for getting all contacts
    String url = "http://192.168.100.2/android_connect/get_contact_details.php?ContactID="+ContactID;

    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Log Errors Here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
public JSONArray search(String search)
{
    // URL for getting all customers
    String url = "http://192.168.100.2/android_connect/search.php?search="+search;

    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Log Errors Here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}   
}
```

**ListView's custom adapater**

GetAllContactListVIew.java

```
   public class GetAllContactListVIewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public String message;
private JSONArray dataArray;
private Activity activity;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;  
public GetAllContactListVIewAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, Activity a){
    this.dataArray = jsonArray;
    this.activity = a;      
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
}   
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.dataArray.length();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}   
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    ListCell cell; //our data model     
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_all_contact_list_view_cell,null);
        cell = new ListCell();
        cell.FullName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_full_name);
        cell.PhoneNumber=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone_number);
        cell.Address=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_address);
        convertView.setTag(cell);           
    }
    else {
        cell = (ListCell)convertView.getTag();
    }
    //change data here
    try{
    JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position); // setting data in our model from the JSONArray obtained from server
    cell.FullName.setText(jsonObject.getString("firstName")+" " +jsonObject.getString("lastName"));
    cell.PhoneNumber.setText(" "+jsonObject.getString("phoneNumber"));
    cell.Address.setText(" " + jsonObject.getString("address"));        
    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return convertView;
}
private class ListCell {        
    private TextView FullName;
    private TextView PhoneNumber;
    private TextView Address;
}
}
```

En mi main.java quería establecer los métodos para la onclick EditarTexto búsqueda.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView GetAllContactListView;
private JSONArray jsonArray;
private Button button;
private EditText search;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.GetAllContactListView = (ListView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.GetAllContactListView);
    this.search = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    this.button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);     
    new GetAllContactTask().execute(new ApiConnector());
    GetAllContactListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    this.GetAllContactListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) { // onclick of an item in
                                                    // listview
                    try {
                        // get the contact which was clicked
                        JSONObject contactClicked = jsonArray
                                .getJSONObject(position);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                ((TextView) view).getText(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
}   
public void setListAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    this.GetAllContactListView.setAdapter(new GetAllContactListVIewAdapter(
            jsonArray, this));
}
private class GetAllContactTask extends
        AsyncTask<ApiConnector, Long, JSONArray> {
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
        return params[0].GetAllContacts();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        setListAdapter(jsonArray);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ApiConnector x = new ApiConnector();
                JSONArray jo = new JSONArray();
                jo = ((ApiConnector) x).search(search.getText().toString());
                Log.d("test", jo.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

error logcat:

> 04-17 14:21:59.012: E/Entity Response :(29911):
>   [{"contact_id":"2","firstName":"Bikram","lastName":"Kumar","phoneNumber":"57777344","address":"Beedassy
>   Lane
>   Floreal","email_address":"bikram_k30@yahoo.com","Active":"Yes"},{"contact_id":"3","firstName":"Keshwarparsad","lastName":"Shunker","phoneNumber":"57175795","address":"Beedassy
>   Lane
>   Floreal","email_address":"rishi@gmail.com","Active":"Yes"},{"contact_id":"4","firstName":"Shravan","lastName":"Murachparsad","phoneNumber":"58507542","address":"Petit
>   Raffray","email_address":"shravmurach@gmail.com","Active":"Yes"},{"contact_id":"5","firstName":"Ashlay","lastName":"Seeburrun","phoneNumber":"57844670","address":"Camp
>   Thorel","email_address":"ashlayseeburrun@yahoo.com","Active":"Yes"},{"contact_id":"6","firstName":"Yershlay","lastName":"Seeburrun","phoneNumber":"57768319","address":"Camp
>   Thorel","email_address":"yershlay_seeburrun@gmail.com","Active":"Yes"},{"contact_id":"8","firstName":"Keshav","lastName":"Gupta","phoneNumber":"6975245","address":"Right
>   lane,Flacq","email_address":"kgupta23@hotmail.com","Active":"Yes"},{"contact_id":"10","firstName":"bik","lastName":"dsad","phoneNumber":"5646464","address":"kljlkk","email_address":"lolo@gmail.com","Active":"Yes"}]
>   04-17 14:21:59.043: D/OpenGLRenderer(29911): Enabling debug mode 0
>   04-17 14:21:59.202: I/Timeline(29911): Timeline: Activity_idle id:
>   android.os.BinderProxy@17e7a51a time:43638863 04-17 14:22:24.133:
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29911): getExtractedText on inactive
>   InputConnection 04-17 14:22:24.137: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29911):
>   getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection 04-17 14:22:26.621:
>   I/Timeline(29911): Timeline: Activity_idle id:
>   android.os.BinderProxy@17e7a51a time:43666283
>
> 04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:157)
>   04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
>   04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
>   04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
>   04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
>   04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
>   04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
>   04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   com.example.teldirectfinaltest2.ApiConnector.search(ApiConnector.java:157)
>   04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   com.example.teldirectfinaltest2.MainActivity$GetAllContactTask$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:98)
>   04-17 14:22:37.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29911): at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
>
> 04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:157)
>   04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
>   04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
>   04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
>   04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
>   04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
>   04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
>   04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   com.example.teldirectfinaltest2.ApiConnector.search(ApiConnector.java:157)
>   04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   com.example.teldirectfinaltest2.MainActivity$GetAllContactTask$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:98)
>   04-17 14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856) 04-17 14:23:19.028:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956) 04-17
>   14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 04-17
>   14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 04-17
>   14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 04-17 14:23:19.028:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 04-17
>   14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 04-17 14:23:19.028:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Comment: gracious.post que Logcat completa.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno un problema que se puede ver en el stacktrace,

> MainActivity$GetAllContactTask$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:98) 04-17
>   14:23:19.028: E/AndroidRuntime(30407): at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)

es que estas definiendo un clickListener de un botón dentro del método `onPostExecute()` de tu `Asynctask` `GetAllContactTask`, al definir el listener ahí no se podrá ejecutar correctamente:

```
  private class GetAllContactTask extends
            AsyncTask<ApiConnector, Long, JSONArray> {
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
            return params[0].GetAllContacts();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            setListAdapter(jsonArray);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ApiConnector x = new ApiConnector();
                    JSONArray jo = new JSONArray();
                    jo = ((ApiConnector) x).search(search.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("test", jo.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Ese listener puedes definirlo dentro de `onCreate()` después de:

```
this.button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: por desgracia no funciona.

Comment: que es lo que no funciona? que error obtienes o que mensajevse imprime en el LogCat